# Is it bad to find records in Rails constants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many static roles that are stored in the database as records.

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Role id: 1, name: "admin">, #<Role id: 2, name: "other_role">]>
```

I feel like it might be bad to constantly do `Role.find_by(name: 'admin')` every time I want to use that Role. I know it will exist, as it'll be in the seeds.

**Is it considered bad practice to have a constant in an initializer to find that record on server start?**

```
ADMIN_ROLE = Role.find_by(name: 'admin')
```

Comment: Instead of constant you can use `scope`, Like `scope :admin_role, -> { where(name: 'admin').first }` in role model.

Comment: That's very true. That would clean things up quite a bit. I was also considering performance. That still would require a db hit every time, whereas a constant would be loaded just once right?

Comment: If you put it in the initializer than you'll need to restart the app to get any updated roles. At that point, using a configuration file is probably a better way to go. No need for the database overhead.

Comment: In some cases, for convenience, is preferable to have configurations in the database. So I don't think this can be considered bad if you know what you are doing and it fits the purpose you want to achieve, that is, better performance.